# Htaccess Rewrite Code Giving A Page Not Found Error

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get some URLs pared down and cleaned for SEO purpose on an website I'm working on. The part where the actual URL is rewritten works just fine. The issue is that it gives me a 404 error page.

I'm new to using htaccess and have managed this far piecing things together.

Here is the code that's yielding this result.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/cat/(.*)/$ /products.php?cat=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

To repeat. Changing the URL as it appears in the address bar works, it not recognizing this as the page that is the problem.

Comment: Either it is working just fine, or it gives a 404. What exactly happens?

Comment: It rewrites the URL in the address bar. But the page is a 404 error telling me that that url doesn't exist. To be clear the original url is this: products.php?cat=Beef#1 which becomes this cat/Chicken#1 and the latter is what is reported as missing. I'm omitting the rest of the url there.

Comment: Nothing in the rules suggest `products.php?...` becoming `cat/...`, rather the other way round. One problem is the leading slash in `^/cat/...`, this should be `^cat/...`.